# R load data from the internet and delete colums simultaneously

Tags: r

I want to load Bitcoin-time-series-data from the "crypto"-package an delete some columns simultaneously.
Here ist my code:

```
library(crypto)
Bitcoin <-crypto_history('bitcoin', start_date = '20180101', end_date = '20181231')
```

The output is:

```
> head(Bitcoin)

 slug    symbol    name       date  ranknow    open    high     low   close      volume
1 bitcoin    BTC Bitcoin 2018-01-01       1 14112.2 14112.2 13154.7 13657.2 10291200000
2 bitcoin    BTC Bitcoin 2018-01-02       1 13625.0 15444.6 13163.6 14982.1 16846600192
3 bitcoin    BTC Bitcoin 2018-01-03       1 14978.2 15572.8 14844.5 15201.0 16871900160
4 bitcoin    BTC Bitcoin 2018-01-04       1 15270.7 15739.7 14522.2 15599.2 21783199744
5 bitcoin    BTC Bitcoin 2018-01-05       1 15477.2 17705.2 15202.8 17429.5 23840899072
6 bitcoin    BTC Bitcoin 2018-01-06       1 17462.1 17712.4 16764.6 17527.0 18314600448
```

And now I want to delete the columns ('slug', 'symbol', 'name' and 'ranknow').
It would be best if I implemented that in the previous code. So I can use it in a map-function for multiple dataframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `select` function from dplyr package.

```
library(dplyr)

Bitcoin <-crypto_history('bitcoin', start_date = '20180101', end_date = '20181231') %>%
  select(-slug, -symbol, -name, -rankrow)
```